# Could not find method testImplementation() for arguments [junit:junit:4.12]

Tags: android, gradle, junit, build

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

This is my build.gradle file and I tried many ways but I can't fix this, when I start Android Studio and gradle starts build the project Android Studio throw this error
how can I fix it?( I am new in Android)

Could not find method `testImplementation()` for arguments `[junit:junit:4.12]` on object of type `org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

Comment: I encountered the same issue. Have you found a solution for that yet?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is Google's fault.You need to use your countries letters.So use 'İ' instead 'I'.

```
testİmplementation  'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestİmplementation  'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestİmplementation  'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Thanks for sharing. This problem made me mad.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. Apparently, Turkish İ problem. Everyone gets excited about AI nowadays, but humanity still hasn't solved encoding issues :(

Comment: Does this not make your project incompatible with any other developer around the world? I can't believe that this is the only solution. Also I can't believe we're still having this Java upper/lowercase issue. I use en_us everywhere but obviously I should not have to.

Comment: I can't believe we still have this issue in 2020 :/

Comment: I found this line works, if it is put inside the dependencies block inside the build.gradle file like this:


dependencies {
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
 testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

Answer (score 8):

Well, I know that's not the nicest solution for this but this is what worked. I simply commented these lines out:

```
//testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
//testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2"
```

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 3):

Even though [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests) says

> In your app's top-level build.gradle file, specify the following libraries as dependencies:

... I haven't found an example that works that way.

In fact, [this GoogleSamples Android Unit Test example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/unit/BasicUnitAndroidTest/build.gradle) specifies:

> // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong in the individual module build.gradle files

So, move that line to the **module** build.gradle, **not the top-level** build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide your Gradle version and complete build.gradle ?

Possible issues:

1. You are missing a plugin definition

   `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

or any plugin that implicitly uses the [Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) ? That's where the `testImplementation` comes from.

2. You're using < Gradle 3.x (testImplementation is not available in the previous releases)

Ensure you are using Gradle 3.x+ and that the top level build.gradle has Android Gradle Plugin  3.x+ defined in it :
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin

Answer (score 1):

100% working.

Replace testİmplementation with testImplementation.(İ with I or i)

in your dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha06'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha06'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha06'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha06'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testimplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestimplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestimplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Syncing only active variant
            You can disable this experimental feature from
            File → Settings → Experimental → Gradle → Only sync the active variant

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle file in replace :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Before

I didn't know `implementation` needs to be within `dependencies` in `build.gradle`

```
// build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
```

```sh
gs-spring-boot/initial [master●] » ./gradlew bootRun

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/geoff/work/androidStuff/gs-spring-boot/initial/build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'spring-boot'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator] on root project 'spring-boot' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

### After

```
// build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
}
```

```sh
gs-spring-boot/initial [master●] » ./gradlew bootRun

> Task :bootRun

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by gradle daemon start with user's locale (TR). Starting gradle daemon with EN locale will solve the problem.
In *gradle.properties* file set user language by updating the following line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m -Duser.language=en
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as follows, maybe it will work for you.

before

```
androidtestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

after

```
testImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

before

```
andoidtestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
```

after

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to apply jvm-related plug-ins.
The most basic is like the following:

```
apply  plugin: 'java'
```

or apply other jvm-related plugin

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Add Configurations -->template-->gradle--> Define gradle project field gradle project.

[image]

Comment: Please add some explanation to that image - why do you think that this solves the problem?

Answer (score -1):

One of these 3 methods will work

1)
Project Structure > Project > and change

Gradle Version: 4.6
Android Plugin Version: 3.2.1

2)
change it testImplementation --> testİmplementation

```
 testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

3)

```
    //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'

    //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02'
```

> Clean --> Rebuild

or

> File --> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you pay attention to proper Camel Case. TestImplementation not testimplementation. Unless you follow that convention you will receive an error and it will drive you crazy